# binary search passing list slice instead of whole list

Tags: python, algorithm, list, binary-search

Is this binary search of the sorted list going to be faster if we pass list slice instead of the whole list, where the list has millions of items?

Normal:

```
def binary_search(data, target, low, high):
if low > high:
    return False
else:
    mid = (low + high) // 2
    if target == data[mid]:
        return True
    elif target < data[mid]:
        return binary_search(data, target, low, mid-1)
    else:
        return binary_search(data, target, mid+1, high)
```

With list slice(I had to modify it a bit):

```
def binary_search(data, target, low, high):
if low > high:
    return False
else:
    mid = (low + high) // 2
    if target == data[mid]:
        return True
    elif target < data[mid]:
        return binary_search(data[low:mid-1], target, 0, mid)
    else:
        return binary_search(data[mid+1:high], target, 0, high-mid)
```

I am currently learning about algorithms so i really don't know if this is the best practice or not.

Comment: `data[x:y]` creates a new `list` object; it doesn't return a view into the existing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think with the second approach the `TimeComplexity` is the same as with Normal Binary Search but `Space complexity` is unnecessary increasing..

Your first binary search takes constant `O(1) space`, meaning that the space taken by the algorithm is the same for any number of elements in the array.
But in your second case space complexity is unnecessary increased by O(logn) hence it's inefficient.

Comment: This answer is incorrect regarding the second solution. Assuming data to be python list, in the first step half of the data is copied `data[low:mid-1]` which is o(n) time complexity. Therefore, the whole algorithm can't be faster than o(n). Total time complexity is still o(n).

Answer (score 4):

the problem with the second approach is that such slicing creates another `list` object at each iteration from the original list which means:

- memory allocation
- memory copy from original list

So indexing may become clearer, but performance is actually degraded, resulting to the inverse of the searched effect.